# What's the difference between display:none and *ngIf = 'false'?

Tags: angular

The **`display:none`** is css sheet. It
will remove elements from DOM tree.
The **`ngIf = 'false'`** also remove elements from DOM tree.
What's the difference between them?

Answer (score 20):

### [**`display:none`**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/display)

<kbd>[From MDN Web Docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/display)</kbd>

> The value **`none`** lets you turn off the display of an element; when
>   you use **`none`**, all descendant elements also have their display
>   turned off. The document is rendered as though the element doesn't
>   exist in the document tree.

But when see the DOM of the page using dev tool, still elements **does exist** in the DOM tree. It means elements do not remove completely from the DOM tree.

---

### [**`*ngIf="false"`**](https://angular.io/api/common/NgIf)

Completely remove the elements from the DOM tree. Because of that when it comes to page rendering, compare to **`display:none`**, using **`*ngIf="false"`** serving better performance with fast page rendering.

<kbd>[From Angular Guide](https://angular.io/guide/structural-directives#ngif-case-study)</kbd>

> The [`ngIf`](https://angular.io/api/common/NgIf) directive doesn't hide elements with CSS. It adds and
>   removes them physically from the DOM. Confirm that fact using browser
>   developer tools to inspect the DOM.
>
> When the condition is `false`, `NgIf` removes its host element from the
>   DOM, detaches it from DOM events (the attachments that it made),
>   detaches the component from Angular change detection, and destroys it.
>   The component and DOM nodes can be garbage-collected and free up
>   memory.

---

Following images will describe them well

1) Without using **`display:none`** and **`*ngIf="false"`**

[image]

2) Using **`display:none`** and **`*ngIf="false"`**

[image]

---

### [Comparison of hiding (`display:none`) vs removing (`*ngIf='false'`)](https://angular.io/guide/structural-directives#why-remove-rather-than-hide)

<kbd>[From Angular Guide](https://angular.io/guide/structural-directives#why-remove-rather-than-hide)</kbd>

> The difference between hiding and removing doesn't matter for a simple
>   paragraph. It does matter when the host element is attached to a
>   resource intensive component. Such a component's behavior continues
>   even when hidden. The component stays attached to its DOM element. It
>   keeps listening to events. Angular keeps checking for changes that
>   could affect data bindings. Whatever the component was doing, it keeps
>   doing.
>
> Although invisible, the component—and all of its descendant
>   components—tie up resources. The performance and memory burden can be
>   substantial, responsiveness can degrade, and the user sees nothing.
>
> On the positive side, showing the element again is quick. The
>   component's previous state is preserved and ready to display. The
>   component doesn't re-initialize—an operation that could be expensive.
>   So hiding and showing is sometimes the right thing to do.
>
> But in the absence of a compelling reason to keep them around, your
>   preference should be to remove DOM elements that the user can't see
>   and recover the unused resources with a structural directive like `NgIf`
>   .
>
> These same considerations apply to every structural directive, whether
>   built-in or custom. Before applying a structural directive, you might
>   want to pause for a moment to consider the consequences of adding and
>   removing elements and of creating and destroying components.

Hope this will help you to understand the difference between them.

Answer (score 7):

`display: none;` does not prevent the browser from rendering that element.

`ngIf = "false"` will prevent that item from ever being rendered in the first place. The element will render if/when the `ngIf` evaluates to true, if the expression again changes back to false, then your element will be removed from the DOM tree entirely.

This is not true for `display:none;`. This only results in the element not being displayed and having any other CSS applied to it. `display:none;` will have no affect on the rate at which your page renders/loads.

This means the loading of your page will theoretically be faster using `ngIf`.

Answer (score 4):

**`display:none;`** will remove the DOM elements visual style / physical space from the DOM, Not completely the element itself. Which can be replaced with the attribute **`[Hide]`** in angular.

whereas *ngIf is a angular builtin directive which and **`*ngIf`** if false will remove the element from the DOM

Answer (score 0):

`ngIf` is an angular directive and display:none is a CSS class `property` with value `none`. They have a uniqueness in the way they render the HTML DOM of the page.

### ngIf

`ngIf` directive removes or recreates a portion of the `DOM` based on an expression. As per the `OP` you supply the expression as `false` (**`ngIf = 'flase'`**). Hence, the element will be remove from the DOM.

When an element is removed using `ngIf` its scope is destroyed and a new scope is created when the element is restored. The scope created within `ngIf` inherits from its parent scope using prototypical inheritance.

### display:none

The `display:none` hides the given HTML element. `display` is the CSS class onto the element and sets the display style to none.

Answer (score 0):

@coder explained the difference really well. The fact that "display: none;" doesn't destroy the element also means that if you're using it to hide a component, the component's onDestroy method does not get called, and all its subscriptions will persist

Answer (score -1):

**display:none** hides the element, but if you explore the DOM with the Chrome Dev Tools (for example) you can see that the element is present. It is not removed.
With **ngIf**, the element is removed from the DOM.

**display:none** is the equivalent of **ng-hide/ng-show** in AngularJs.

**Warning!** Is true that using ngIf the page load faster, but if you have an element that will be switching between show and hide more than once, is better to use display:none or ngHide, because **every change between** ngIf = false and ngIf = true, **will generate a request to the server**.

By!